# Concurrent parallel execution

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

I am trying to execute several python code at the same time in different folder  using concurrent futures. The code run fine but when i check the subfolders I don't see any output so I am assuming the python code that I am calling were never executed. 
The code first find a python script with specific name in all of the folders then call them in parallel. The write the output in another text file so my goal is to have them write the text file in folders that the script is located. 
for example:

```
Folder A
ReadTextFileV9-10.py
Folder B
ReadTextFileV9-10.py
```

I want the out put to be

```
Folder A
ReadTextFileV9-10.py
Output.txt 

Folder B
ReadTextFileV9-10.py
Output.txt
```

This is my code.

```
from concurrent import futures
import re
import os
import timeit
import os
import glob
import re
from glob import glob
import subprocess

FileList = [];

start_dir = os.getcwd();
pattern   = "ReadTextFileV9-10.py"

for dir,_,_ in os.walk(start_dir):
    FileList.extend(glob(os.path.join(dir,pattern))) ;

print(FileList)

def Run_Code(Str):

    return subprocess.run(Str)
futuress=[]
def main_function(FileList):
    with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        #results = executor.map(Run_Code, FileList)

        for file in FileList:
            future = executor.submit(subprocess.run, file)

            futuress.append(future)
        return futuress

results=main_function(FileList)
```

I appreciate if any one can help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: What are the contents of `Output.txt`? It seems like the writing of `Output.txt` is tied to the execution of `ReadTextFileV9-10.py`, not the code you have posted here... which makes this hard to debug. A simplified example would go a long way.

Comment: @sam you are absolutely right, the Output.txt is tied to the execution of ReadTextFileV9_10.py the code that i posted need to execute the ReadTextFileV9-10.py,  so for example if I  go to Folder A and execute ReadTextFileV9-10.py I will get the Output.txt so  ReadTextFileV9-10.py works fine but the issue is that the code I posted is not able to call script properly but I am not sure why.